# How to enable anisotropic filtering and anti-aliasing with mupen64plus 1.99.3

Tags: 10.04, video

OS: Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit
I have searched alll over for how to enable these with the mupen emulator. Thought I might check and see if anyone here has knowledge on this.
http://code.google.com/p/mupen64plus/
I'm really hoping I don't have to go back to Windows to use Project 64 to get these. And before anyone says "Project 64 rocks with wine" well I'm sure it does, but no Anti-Aliasing in wine...
Thanks in advance! ^^

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured out how to configure mupen to use AA & AF. Problem is you have to configure config.cpp in the Rice Video plugin by hand. The option for multi-sampling and anisotropic filtering was already there, but set to 0. Using this guide I downloaded the HG and built it with the config altered and unaltered, but both ways I get an error running mupen64plus.

```
    ethan@ethans-mac:~/Emulators/N64/mupenHG/test$ ./mupen64plus --resolution 1920x1080 --windowed --verbose /home/ethan/Emulators/ROMs_ISOs_IMGs/N64/Zelda\:\ OOT/Legend\ of\ Zelda\,\ The\ -\ Ocarina\ of\ Time\ \(USA\).n64
 __  __                         __   _  _   ____  _             
|  \/  |_   _ _ __   ___ _ __  / /_ | || | |  _ \| |_   _ ___ 
| |\/| | | | | '_ \ / _ \ '_ \| '_ \| || |_| |_) | | | | / __|  
| |  | | |_| | |_) |  __/ | | | (_) |__   _|  __/| | |_| \__ \  
|_|  |_|\__,_| .__/ \___|_| |_|\___/   |_| |_|   |_|\__,_|___/  
             |_|         http://code.google.com/p/mupen64plus/  
Mupen64Plus Console User-Interface Version 1.99.3

UI-console: attached to core library 'Mupen64Plus Core' version 1.99.3
            Includes support for Dynamic Recompiler.
Core: Goodname: Legend of Zelda, The - Ocarina of Time (U) (V1.0) [!]
Core: Name: THE LEGEND OF ZELDA
Core: MD5: 5BD1FE107BF8106B2AB6650ABECD54D6
Core: CRC: ec7011b7 7616d72b
Core: Imagetype: .v64 (byteswapped)
Core: Rom size: 33554432 bytes (or 32 Mb or 256 Megabits)
Core: ClockRate = f
Core: Version: 1449
Core: Manufacturer: 43000000
Core: Cartridge_ID: 4c5a
Core: Country: USA
Core: PC = 80000400
Core: EEPROM type: 0
UI-Console: Cheat codes disabled.
UI-console: using Video plugin: 'Mupen64Plus OpenGL Video Plugin by Rice' v1.99.3
UI-console: Video plugin library: ./mupen64plus-video-rice.so
UI-console: using Audio plugin: 'Mupen64Plus SDL Audio Plugin' v1.99.3
UI-console: Audio plugin library: ./mupen64plus-audio-sdl.so
UI-console: using Input plugin: 'Mupen64Plus SDL Input Plugin' v1.99.3
UI-console: Input plugin library: ./mupen64plus-input-sdl.so
UI-console: using RSP plugin: 'Hacktarux/Azimer High-Level Emulation RSP Plugin' v1.99.3
UI-console: RSP plugin library: ./mupen64plus-rsp-hle.so
Core Error: broken Video plugin; function(s) not found.
UI-Console: error from core while attaching Video plugin.
Core Status: Rom closed.
```

Thoughts or solutions? Thanks.
Links used to figure this out: http://code.google.com/p/mupen64plus/wiki/CompilingFromHg?colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&sort=-id

Comment: Second link: http://code.google.com/p/mupen64plus/issues/detail?id=338&can=1&q=multisampling&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: `Core Error: broken Video plugin; function(s) not found.` is not much help. Try running it in debug mode to get additional info about the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Nvidia you can override the Antialiasing and Anisotropic Filtering settings globally using the **nvidia-settings** application.

http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/6316/70292226.jpg

There might be a similar control panel for ATI?